# How can pass dynamic Image name?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-intent, android-fragments

I am developing Android Web App.In this code`imageView.setImageDrawable(R.drawable.img1)`,I need to pass dynamic image value for img1.How can I do?

Comment: why not placing your images in assets folder?

Comment: if i stored in assert folder,how can i set image from assert folder in ImageView?

Comment: BirmapFactory.decodeStream

Comment: can you give sample code pls?

Comment: or Drawable.createFromStream i think this one is more general

Comment: Loading Image from assets : https://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/10/02/store-and-use-files-in-assets/

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you try like this?

int id = getResources().getIdentifier("yourpackagename:drawable/" + img1, null, null);

imageview.setImageResource(id);